# webdriver print with desired pageWidth pageHeight

Tags: webdriver

I was searching and trying many things to change page size of generated PDF with webdriver.

I already read and studied those following links

https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#print-page

https://webdriver.io/docs/api/webdriver/#printpage

https://github.com/jlipps/simple-wd-spec

as so far I was able to succesuflly use `{"background": true}` but when I try to change page size with using `{"pageWidth": 29.70, "pageHeight": 42.00}` (desired A3 format) then I have no success, I mean generated PDF is still 8,50x11,00 inches but I wanted A3 format which should be 11,69x16,54 inches.

Size of page in PDF I check using AcrobatReader:
[image]

So I wanted to ask if I pass `{"pageWidth": 29.70, "pageHeight": 42.00}` incorectly or there is another issue which I do not understand.

Answer (score 1):

I just went through the spec and I see that it mentions this regarding page dimensions:

> 10. Let `pageWidth` be the result of getting a property with default named `width` and with a default of 21.59 from page.
> 11. Let `pageHeight` be the result of getting a property with default named `height` and with a default of 27.94 from page.

The wording is a bit misleading, but I interpret it as "get page height from a property called `height`", `pageHeight` seems to be an internal name used in the spec, the actual name of the property in the options object is simply `height`. (vice-a-versa for width)

So can you try this?: `{"width": 29.70, "height": 42.00}`

Comment: It can be. As for now on chome it is still not working will try with FireFox

Comment: Using FireFox (geckodriver.exe) i got the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I finally was able find the proper way

```
{
    "page":{
            "width": 29.70
            ,"height": 42.00
        }
    ,"margin":{
            "top": 2
            ,"bottom": 2
            ,"left": 2
            ,"right": 2
        }
    ,"scale": 0.5
    ,"orientation":"landscape"
    ,"shrinkToFit": true
    ,"background": true
    ,"pageRanges": ["1", "1-1"]
}
```